# Can an I use both WordPress rest API and WooCommerce rest API in the sapapis ame mobile application

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to build a mobile app using react native, for a wordpress website I built for a client. The site uses wocommerce for the ecommerce section but has other core WordPress functionality like it allows multiple authors. I want to know if I can use both WordPress rest API and woocommerce API on the same mobile app.

I know this may be a silly question, but for a beginner; as this is the first time I'm developing mobile apps, I just want to know.

I find it confusing because most tutorials I see looks like they use only woocommerce API since they say something like "building shopping cart app with woocommerce API and react native".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can study about axios, for example, to handle HTTP requests. On the request you can specify wich api url to use on the request.

Example:

```
axios.request({
  url: '/sessions/sign_in'
  method: 'POST',
  baseURL: 'your api base url',
  data: {
   user
  }
})
```